# How to send a message to a console application from an IIS hosted WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, logging, console

I've developed a WCF service that I self hosted in a console application during development, then more recently deployed in IIS on the server.  The console application provided a useful view of what was happening in the system at that point in time, and I would like to replicate that now that I am hosting the service in IIS.

The easiest way I can see to do this would be to develop a new console application whose sole job is to receive a message and output it.  I can then update my WCF service's log method to send the message to the new application.

I don't want the console application to always be turned on.  I want to start it whenever I need to monitor the current status of the system, but leave the service running if I close the console.

Any thoughts on how best to achieve this?  I was thinking another self hosted WCF service, and perhaps just have the main service ping "localhost:8080/ConsoleLogger?message=abc".  Seems a bit messy though, and not extendible (like having the output on a webpage instead of the console so I can see it over a network).

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Why not use tracing and logging?

Comment: @Steven Berkovitz You tell me.  I was asking a question, not ruling out tracing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WCF broadcasting for that, subscribe different clients to it to receive messages. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756931.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - it got me looking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

http://www.paulrohde.com/building-a-really-simple-wcf-p2p-application/

It's a great tutorial on creating a simple pier to pier chatroom, which is easily adapted to suit my purposes, allowing me to connect a console application to the server and monitor from multiple machines.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work in IIS, as IIS doesn't support NetPeerTCPBinding.  I'm thinking I might have to make this a windows service and have something in between communicating between IIS and the windows service on the server.  

Unless anyone can think of how I would call a separate logging app that communicates through NetPeerTCPBinding?